# Universal application in android (phone and tablet)

Tags: android

I am developing an Universal application in android which should run on android phone and android tablet, I know the procedure to make an application for android phone but how to make for android tablet, Please guide me for this.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: also see answer at [Universal App for both tablets+handsets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7735334/383414)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should support the different screen layouts. Take a look over at [the multiple screen page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

It gives you, amongst explanation how to save multiple versions of files for different resolutions, als this piece of code for the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

You can make different drawable directories etc, as explained in the link.

Comment: i had put this support screen but yet in google play it's dispaly that designed for phones. i had make table layout also yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still looking for another answer, but I made a tool that can scale your layouts to the four different density buckets out there. If you create your layouts for one base-line density bucket, this tool can scale your layouts onto a tablet size screen:

http://onemanmobile.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-scale-your-android-layouts-to.html

It should take everyone very little time to make their simple Android app into a universal app for small, normal, large and x-large devices.