# How to get full screen size in Eee Pad using HoneyComb

Tags: android

HI,
I have a question to want to be asked.

I have a Eee Pad TF101. 
I make the screen size with following procedure yard, but I always get 320*480

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager() . getDefaultDisplay() . getMetrics(dm);
Map.screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
Map.screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;
```

Could you tell me how I should obtain full screen size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure you set your `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />`. Obviously your app can have another version, so you'll have to replace the 8 with [your api version](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#intro).

Answer (score 0):

[Universal application in android (phone and tablet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813832/universal-application-in-android-phone-and-tablet/5814026#5814317)