# Universal App for both tablets+handsets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I am developing a single application for both tablets and for handsets..My app is currently running fine on handsets(as according to layouts and all)..but i have no idea for how to distinguish it for handsets/tablets. I have seen some of the answers in Stackoverflow.com too, in which some people answered that use different layout-large,layout-xlarge.

but if the layout differs and we follow the above scenario,then in programming,it is written setcontentView(R.layout.---).

So we have to mention here also that setContentView(R.layout-large.---)..I am so confused with this..Can anyone suggest me something...

Comment: also see answer at [Universal application in android (phone and tablet)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5814317/383414)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to name the folder differently those contain same nameLayout.xml

like so

```
--layout
   -- myLayout.xml
--layout-large
   -- myLayout.xml
--layout-xlarge
   -- myLayout.xml
```

on code, you only need to use

```
secContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
```

android will find the right one for you.

Comment: So when we write it as R.layout.myLayout,it would not fetch the layout of first one only??? and is there any other way to distinguish it??

Comment: No, if a user is using a xlarge device, android will go look up myLayout.xml in layout-xlarge. So this way, you dont have to worry about how to distinguish it. It's done automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

The android os will select the appropriate folder based on the device dimensions and other properties.

So you can keep the resource name same in all the folders and android will pick from the appropriate folder.

Comment: resource name will be the xml file name or the folder name??

Comment: the xml files name, or the other files names such as the images in the drawable folders. These are the permissible folder names that can be used in the res folder http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Is there any other way to build universal app for both handsets and tablets?